# Optimization of running total calculation in SQL for multiple values per join condition

Tags: sql, optimization, informix

I have the following table (test_table):

```
date   value
---------------
d1      10.0
d1      20.0
d2      60.0
d2      10.0
d2     -20.0
d3      40.0
```

I calculate the running total as follows. I use the same query twice, because first I need to calculate the values for a specific date, and afterwards I can calculate the running total. Otherwise, joining the two tables where date is not unique, would get me too many results for each date:

```
  SELECT t1.date, SUM(t2.value) AS total

    FROM

 (SELECT date, SUM(value) AS value FROM test_table GROUP BY date) AS t1

    JOIN

 (SELECT date, SUM(value) AS value FROM test_table GROUP BY date) AS t2

      ON t1.date >= t2.date
GROUP BY t1.date
ORDER BY t1.date
```

This gives me (which is fine):

```
date    total
-------------
d1       30.0
d2       80.0
d3      120.0
```

**BUT**, this query isn't very efficient, because I need to change conditions in two places, if necessary. In production, the test_table is a lot bigger (> 4 Mio. rows), and the query takes too much time to complete. **Question**: How can I avoid using the same query twice?

Comment: CTE maybe an answer for you

Comment: Execute the first query to temporary table:`SELECT...INTO TEMP <name> WITH NO LOG` (I suppose the amount of data here will considerable smaller of 4Mi.rows), then summarize the temp to get the second result... since will be less rows to sum.

Answer (score 0):

@Kiril, check if following works for you:

```
SELECT a1.date, a1.value, SUM(a2.value) Running_Total
FROM test_table a1, test_table a2
WHERE a1.date >= a2.date
GROUP BY a1.date, a1.value
ORDER BY a1.date, a1.value;

o/p:
date          value    running_total
01/01/2014     10               30
01/01/2014     20               30
01/11/2014    -20               80
01/11/2014     10               80
01/11/2014     60               80
01/15/2014     40              120
```

If you need further refinement, you can load this data into a temp table and:

```
select distinct date , running_total from tem_table;
```

---

One more simple 2 step method:

```
Step1: (This will give you distinct dates in column 1)
create temp table tt (val_date date, val_value smallint);
insert into tt (val_date, val_date)
select date, sum(value) from test_table group by date;

Step2:
SELECT a1.val_date, SUM(a2.val_value) Running_Total
FROM tt a1, tt a2
WHERE a1.val_date >= a2.val_date
GROUP BY a1.val_date;
```

**Note: Both the methods are tried and tested.**

Thanks & Cheer,

Happy Optimizing.